# About solr auto complete query and integrating in the html

Tags: solr, aem, solrj

Could some provide inputs for the below

1>I want to use solr auto complete feature.If i have a core as abc, what will the solr  query say for search key word  "spell check".

2> How to build the query in AEM CQ5 using solrj  could it be using jquery.Any sample code will be helpfull??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

look at example hope so it will help you.
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/apache-solr/solr-autocomplete-example/